# Postgres FTS. Tweak parsing behavior

Tags: postgresql

Question is regarding FTS configuration.

```
SELECT * FROM ts_debug('english',
  '1056
01:31:06,375 --> 01:31:11,004
I hear it. I think there''s some guys
coming this way, a lot of them.

1057
01:31:11,172 --> 01:31:12,678
We gotta get out of here.');
```

[image]
I have a plenty of series subtitles that contains time intervals where in episode this phrase is takes place, like for example

```
01:31:06,375 --> 01:31:11,004.
```

When FTS parses text it segregates whole interval to individual integers like it shown in example above.

Is it any way to make FTS to parse this intervals as intervals or at leas as 2 timestamps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pre-process the string with

```
regexp_replace(searchstring, '(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d),(\d\d\d)', '\1\2\3\4', 'g')
```

Then `01:31:12,678` will turn to `013112678`, which will work fine with full text search.